# Disable checkboxes after a certain condition is met using only Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm trying to create a function that will disable all remaining unchecked checkboxes in my form after 5 boxes ***are*** checked.

I am able to pull the values(using .length) to verify that 5 checkboxes have in fact been checked, I cannot get the disable() function wired to the remaining checkboxes properly. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

JS logic is below:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
       let Checkboxes = 
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').length <-verifies checkbox total;

    Checkboxes.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        checkboxLimiter();
    });
});

function checkboxLimiter() {
    let markedBoxCount = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length; <-verifies "checked" checkbox total;

    if (markedBoxCount == 5){
        disable();
    }
}

function disable() {
    let unmarkedBoxCount = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)') <-selector for remaining "unchecked" checkboxes;
   ;
    unmarkedBoxCount.disabled = true;
```

And here is the HTML for reference:

```
<div id="strengthsJar">

        <div id="stJar">
            <p>Strategic Thinking</p>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="usertype"> <input
                type="checkbox" name="attribute" id="st-attribute" value="(1,1)"></label>

        </div>

        <div id="eJar">
            <p>Executing</p>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="usertype"> <input
                type="checkbox" name="attribute" id="e-attribute" value="(1,-1)">
                Achiever
            </label>
        </div>

        <div id="rbJar">
            <p>Relationship Building</p>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="usertype"> <input
                type="checkbox" name="attribute" id="rb-attribute" value="(-1,1)">
                Adaptability
            </label>
        </div>
        <div id="iJar">
            <p>Influencing</p>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="usertype"> <input
                type="checkbox" name="attribute" id="i-attribute" value="(-1,-1)">
                Activator

            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay a couple of things first:

1.)

```
 let Checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').length
```

doing this you will set the Checkboxes variable to the number equal to the length of the array of all the checkboxes in the document not to the array itself so you cannot add an eventlistener on a number.

2.)

```
    Checkboxes.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        checkboxLimiter();
    });
```

and

```
let unmarkedBoxCount = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)') ;
unmarkedBoxCount.disabled = true;
```

you cannot perform an operation on the whole array of DOM nodes all at once, you have to iterate over them and addlisteners or disable them one by one.

3.)

```
    Checkboxes.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    checkboxLimiter();
    });
```

you cannot check the checkbox if you prevent the default actions here.

Here is the working code, one difference is that I'm disabling the rest of the checkboxes after you check two of them as I didn't want to add more checkboxes to keep the example simple.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="strengthsJar">

    <div id="stJar">
      <p>Strategic Thinking</p>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="usertype">
        <input type="checkbox" name="attribute" id="st-attribute" value="(1,1)">
      </label>

    </div>

    <div id="eJar">
      <p>Executing</p>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="usertype">
        <input type="checkbox" name="attribute" id="e-attribute" value="(1,-1)"> Achiever
      </label>
    </div>

    <div id="rbJar">
      <p>Relationship Building</p>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="usertype">
        <input type="checkbox" name="attribute" id="rb-attribute" value="(-1,1)"> Adaptability
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="iJar">
      <p>Influencing</p>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="usertype">
        <input type="checkbox" name="attribute" id="i-attribute" value="(-1,-1)"> Activator

      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      let Checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

      for (let i = 0; i < Checkboxes.length; i++)
        Checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          checkboxLimiter();
        });
    });

    function checkboxLimiter() {
      let markedBoxCount = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

      if (markedBoxCount == 2) {
        disable();
      }
    }

    function disable() {
      let unmarkedBoxCount = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)');
      for (let i = 0; i < unmarkedBoxCount.length; i++)
        unmarkedBoxCount[i].disabled = true;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of mistakes, so this will work for example

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // we need to get all checkbox elements, not its length
  let Checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')

  // Checkboxes is nodelist, so we need to add event listener 
  // on every element in it, like this for example
  Checkboxes.forEach( checkbox => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
      checkboxLimiter();
    });
  });
});

function checkboxLimiter() {
  let markedBoxCount = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

  if (markedBoxCount == 3){
    disable();
  }
}

function disable() {
  let unmarkedBoxCount = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)');

  // same thing as Checkboxes
  unmarkedBoxCount.forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.disabled = true
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic has some errors
Try this:

```
let Checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'); 

for(var i = 0; i < Checkboxes.length; i++) {
    Checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        checkboxLimiter(this);
    });
}

function checkboxLimiter(checkbox) {
    let markedBoxCount = 
        document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
    if (markedBoxCount > 2){
        checkbox.checked = false;
    };
};
```

In this example, I disable checkbox with 2 checkeds